# scala project is not taking logback xml configuration when passed via JVM argument

Tags: scala, logging, sbt, logback, slf4j

I have a scala project where i am using scala-slf4j logging and logback. When the project is executed via command line as below

```
java -jar <sample_project.jar> -Dlogback.configurationFile=/tmp/logback.xml
```

It uses logger class as '**ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger**' but is not taking the logback.xml configuration.

Same works fine if i put the logback configuration xml under **/src/main/resources**.

```scala
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

object SampleProj {
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  logger.info("SCALA Logging")
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2",
"com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % "2.1.2",
```

Another approach which is tried is extracted the scala project jar and executed the main class as below

```
java com.test.SampleProj -Dlogback.configurationFile=/tmp/logback.xml
```

Some other methods i tried was,

1. Set the classpath and put the logback xml
2. passing as "**-Dlogger.file=/tmp/logger.xml**"
3. passing as **-Dlogger.resource=/tmp/logger.xml**

Can someone help me in resolving this.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting your file encoding? http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Setup-Notes.html Also, are you getting any warnings/errors?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.@NathanielFord. It working now.

Comment: Did that help? Or are you still stuck? @Gopi

Comment: VM argument needs to be passed like this. java com.test.SampleProj -Dlogback.configurationFile=/tmp/logback.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments to the java should be as below.

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/tmp/logback.xml com.test.SampleProj
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solutions above were not enough. My problem was that the `logback.xml` file was not read by default.

I believe that the solution provided at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Setup-Notes.html, by specifying the file encoding works, it is better to fix that from the shell.

In my shell, I run the following:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

After that, the `logback.xml` was read properly.